# How to track the whole Chrome's history?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, privacy, history, private-browsing

I have a question that I can't find an answer for. Is there a way to track the whole Google Chrome's history (including Incognito mode), before some records are deleted?

I feel like my kids are browsing websites that they shouldn't. I believe that disabling Incognito mode won't help as they might find a way to overcome that.

It could be an extension, app, trick or whatever else. I have an access to this computer every day. It's my personal computer which they use mostly to play some games and watch YouTube.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just check the DNS entries and see if one pops-up a thought.

Open windows power shell and run ipconfig -displaynds

"To open an elevated PowerShell prompt, in the taskbar search, type powershell. Now see the result Windows PowerShell which appears on the top. Right-click on it and select Run as Administrator."

[image]
[image]

Feel free to test it out!

First just make sure to first flush entries to avoid enormous output. (ipconfig -flushdns)

Now open Chrome in incognito, access some random porn site or anything you like for that matter, and then check over cmd.

I now this doesn't answer your question directly, however it might as well help regarding your concern:

> I feel like my kids are browsing websites that they shouldn't. I
>   believe that disabling Incognito mode won't help as they might find a
>   way to overcome that.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a perfect solution. It probably wouldn't hurt to ask if there is a way to save this to a .txt file (or any other file that I can access later)?